# How to make sure that only the administrator can change passwords

Tags: 14.04, users, administrator

How do I make sure that a non-administrator user can not change his own password? I want only administrator to do that.

Comment: What does `/etc/pam.d/passwd` contain?

Comment: @muru I don't know sir. Can't understand what's written there.

Comment: I didn't ask you to interpret it. Just post the contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the SETUID bit from `passwd` binary:

```
sudo chmod u-s /usr/bin/passwd
```

**although this is not recommended.**

The `/usr/bin/passwd` binary is a SETUID executable with owner as `root`, so when `passwd` is executed by anyone it is run as `root` (so necessary changes in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` files can be done). By removing the SETUID bit, we have removed this capability.

Comment: Surely `passwd` makes use of some kernel library function or something? Is `passwd` the only way to change a password?

Comment: @cat There's nothing stopping you from editing `/etc/shadow` by hand. Eventually you just need the sufficient _capability_ to edit `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: _"You can remove the SETUID bit from passwd binary"_ - And then a system update comes along and updates your `/usr/bin/passwd`, reverting your permission change...

Comment: @marcelm Fedora [last changed `passwd(1)` a year ago](https://fedorahosted.org/passwd/browser/passwd.c), so maybe this happens? But I think, passwd is quite a small and "finished" utility, unlikely to get updates.

Comment: @marcelm If you are persistent, and if there is no security upgrade for `passwd` package's binaries, you can always held back the package `passwd` from auto-upgrading: `sudo apt-mark hold passwd`. Also there are many ways to automate the `chmod`-ing stuff if the package is upgraded.

Comment: Although 30 years ago Admin could look at users' password and change them on mainframes and minicomputers it has legal and ethical implications. Subsequently Admins could only reset passwords and when the user signed on they had to immediately change it to one only they knew and no one else.